# What does the dollar sign represent in front of lines?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

I am new to coding and trying to do something with an API and i keep seeing a dollar sign in front of code without specifying where it is being written.

Here is an example:

[image]

I know this dollar sign appears in git bash, however when I run the code it doesn't work. Is it the terminal for macOS or Linux (I am currently on Windows)? I know this is a simple question but I just can't seem to find a solid answer anywhere.

Comment: The dollar sign just let's you know that the line is ran on a terminal line. You are only supposed to copy everything after the symbol.

Comment: also called a prompt. Don't type it with the command

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you mentioned, the dollar sign appears in git bash, right before where any shell commands you type appear. All the dollar sign is signifying is that what comes after is meant to be run on the command line (it is not actually a part of the command). So instead of entering and executing

```
$ pip install [package]
```

As your command, simply execute:

```
pip install [package]
```